# ImportError: cannot import name filename

Tags: python, import, circular-dependency

I have a directory structure like this which houses django MVP files - b and c are individual apps on the main website:

a/b/models.py

a/c/models.py

In `c/models.py`, I can do `"from b.models import "ClassName""`, but when I do `"from c.models import "Class2Name""` in b.models.py, I get the error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name "Class2Name"
```

I see this might be a circular dependency issue, but I'm not clear if it is.